# Problem adding undetected resolution ASUS VA32AQ

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, thinkpad

I've got a new monitor that I'm using as an external for my thinkpad.  It is an [ASUS VA32AQ](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/VA32AQ/).  It has 2560x1440 resolution, which works fine when plugged into my work PC, via the DisplayPort.

When I plug it into my ubuntu laptop however -- via the VGA, because I only have VGA and mini-DP on the laptop, it defaults to 1920x1080.

I followed [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions) to add the undetected resolution:

```
cvt 2560 1440
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP2 2560x1440_60.00
```

Then I opened up the displays gui and switched to the new resolution.  Here is what I got:

[image]

What gives?

Here is the output of xrandr with no arguments:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.04 +  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 393mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
   2560x1440_60.00  59.96* 
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Weirdly, it thinks that the VGA port is "DP2".  Not sure if this matters.

And here is the output of the `lshw` command:

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

This is a Thinkpad X250 with ubuntu 16.04.

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Have you ever used that same VGA-DP adapter in a different computer/OS and managed to obtain higher resolutions? Many (most) such adapters have limitations.

Comment: So you're saying that I'd likely get it to work with an adaptor that'd allow me to use the mini displayport with an HDMI cable?  I can't find any documentation online about how resolution is only 2560x1440 for the digital ports, with less for the analog.

Comment: Any analog-digital or digital-analog converter may have a maximum resolution allowed. Please make sure yours supports higher than 1080P before anything else. If it's an hardware limitation then the answer is obvious and has nothing to do with Ubuntu. OTOH, if you're sure it supports higher resolutions by testing it (the manufacturers' info isn't always reliable, especially if from a shady brand), then you *might* have a case for AskUbuntu.

Comment: Implicitly you're saying that none of the procedures that I've used for adding undetected resolutions are incorrect.  Is that accurate?

Comment: And it seems odd that the digital/analog issue would lead to a horizontally-squeezed screen.

Comment: Honestly I've nothing else to add. My last comments is self-explanatory. Perhaps you want to [edit] and give details about the adapter you're using. It may or may not be possible to gather useful information about it. The main point still: Have you tried it elsewhere and were you able to set higher resolutions or, at least, do you have the manufacturer's specifications saying it does support higher resolutions? If not then please find out first.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to rule out that there are any problems with how I have used ubuntu to add an undetected resolution.  I will now pursue other avenues.

Answer (score 0):

I just picked one of these monitors up on sale and found my ~ 7-year-old laptop gfx card could only support lower refresh rates at this resolution. Specifically the max refresh rate I can drive this monitor it seems to be 40 Hz, but ymmv.

```
 cvt 2560 1440 40
 xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_40.00"  201.00  2560 2720 2984 3408  1440 1443 1448 1476 
 -hsync +vsync
 xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "2560x1440_40.00"
 xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440_40.00
```